# OWIN OAuth Token endpoint wildcard support

Tags: .net, oauth, asp.net-web-api, owin

We are implementing a web api project using a base path for Tenant resolution (i.e. /Tenant/Api/controller)

We ran into problems implementing the auth code for the tenants. We would like to have a /{Tenant}/Token to enable auth request depending on the tenant. However we can't seem to map the token endpoint in OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions.

Any pointers to how we should proceed would be welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OAuth2 AS MW has an event called OnMatchEndpoint where yuo can determine if the incoming request is an authorize request or a token request. It's meant for this exact type of check.

Something like this:

```
var authSvr = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    AllowInsecureHttp = true,
    AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Passive,
    //AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/authorize"),
    Provider = new OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        OnMatchEndpoint = async ctx =>
        {
            if (ctx.Request.Uri.LocalPath == "/authorize")
            {
                ctx.MatchesAuthorizeEndpoint();
            }
        },
```

Except in yours you'd be more dynamic checking the `ctx.Request.Uri.LocalPath` for the tenant.